# Comprehensive guide to using spoiler markup properly - can haz?

Tags: support

Seems like every time I try to use the spoiler markup, I spend five minutes typing my question and twenty minutes trying to remember how to create paragraph breaks in spoiler markup.

For example, I can never remember how to make this:

> One
>  
>  Two

look like this:

```
One

Two
```

while still preserving the spoiler hover effect.

**Can we get a comprehensive guide to spoiler markup?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To do what you want just add two spaces at the end of the line:

```
>! 1
>!   
>! 2
```

Which renders (note that for some reason the first paragraph break renders shorter than others):

> 1
>
>  2

While that's particularly annoying I'm not sure there's much more to spoiler markdown. Also note if you're doing multiple paragraphs you'll need a >! to start each one off

As noted by badp, other full-line markdown (bullet points, blockquotes, numbered lists) don't work inside of spoilers, so you'll need do use raw HTML to add those if necessary.

Generally try to keep only text content in spoilers, and only so much as necessary.

Comment: Additional note: whenever you want fancy formatting inside a spoiler block, such as lists, you'll _have_ to use HTML tags.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using double spaces to create explicit newlines on two consecutive lines:

> One
>
> Two

The code is

```
>!One   
>!  
>!Two
```

And each of the first two lines has two spaces at the end